# Can you do a redirect in .htaccess, and preserve the URI?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way to use .htaccess to redirect example.net to example.com, so that the URI example.net stays the same in the client's browser?

Answer (score 0):

I found these examples from [this](http://forum.powweb.com/archive/index.php/t-4932.html) link:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mychatfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

I haven't tested these out though.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you want is two sites which appear exactly the same, but neither one redirects to the other. You want the person who visits `example.net` to see the same stuff as is on `example.com`, but they should still see `example.net` in their browser address bar.

There are a few ways of doing this. The simplest, of course, is to simply upload the same content to both sites, but this might make updating tricky. Another is to set one domain as an alias of the other; exactly how to do this will depend on your server configuration. It would be simpler, and would perhaps be better for SEO purposes, to redirect one domain to the other.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
# 302 is a temporary redirect. Use it for testing purposes. Once you're sure it works, change it to 301.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the domain *example.net* to point to *example.com* then the best way isn't rewriting it, but to park that domain to *example.com* and the app. for that is basically titled as **Parked Domains** that's in **Domains** section if your control panel is **cPanel** or if your web hosting account features an app. that can park a domain.